# Is it possible to debug costmap2d plugin?

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using vscode with ROS extension installed and I would like to debug my custom costmap plugins but not sure how to start to debugger for it. ROS navigation packages are installed as binary and currently I am using ROS Noetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396735/is-it-possible-to-debug-costmap2d-plugin?/) by [rappy](https://answers.ros.org/users/76966/rappy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2022-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-02-26**:
Which operating system are you using?

**Comment by [rappy](https://answers.ros.org/users/76966/rappy/) on 2022-02-28**:
I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, a costmap plugin can be debugged but it takes some effort.

The costmap plugins are loaded into the `move_base` process and execute there. You need to build the navigation stack from source in your local `catkin_ws`, and tell catkin_make to create a Debug build:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

You can then "attach" the debugger to an already-running `move_base` process, or temporarily remove move_base from your launch file and start it using the debugger.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1